# Interior of a compact manifold with boundary is compact

Tags: manifolds

In the context of manifold with boundary, closed manifold, compact manifold I have the following question in my mind : Let $M$ be a compact manifold with non-empty boundary $\partial M$. Then $\operatorname{int}( M) =M-\partial M$ is a manifold without boundary. Can $\operatorname{int}(M)$ be a COMPACT manifold without boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Can open set be compact? (I am assuming that you have not in mind a compact manifold **minus** its boundary, because there are many affirmative examples, in particular closed balls).

Comment: Oh yes I understand, asked a stupid question.